# Best data type to store formatted texts in ABAP dictionary

Tags: abap

What would be the best data type in data dictionary to store formatted texts? The size of the formatted texts ranges from 20 to 10,000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a field of type STRING as a non-key field in a DB (transparent) table.

In SE11, if you click the "Predefined Type" button, it opens up the Data Type column so you can directly enter "STRING" as the type.

Or you can create/look for a data element based on STRING.

(That is to say, I tested this on a SAP system installed with MS SQL Server. It is possible that different restrictions apply to other databases).

Comment: Thank you mydoghasworms. I am using string now and will come back 2 weeks later to let you know if it works.

Comment: A string is of course useful for storing just about anything; I'm sorry I didn't ask: What do you mean by "formatted"? (If you mean that it contains special characters like tabs and line feeds, for example, then it is of course perfect).

Comment: I wanted to say the texts will be long.